# 「パスワードを入力しダウンロード」を自動化

Tags: python, mechanize

kienuというファイルアップローダーで，パスワードを入力しダウンロードする作業を自動化したいと思っています．
web上ではフォームにパスワードを入力し，送信すると自動的にダウンロードが開始されます．
例えば以下のリンクでは「full123」と入力し，DOWNLOADボタンをクリックします．
https://kie.nu/22W5

pythonのmechanizeでフォームに入力しsubmit()すれば，その時点でダウンロードが開始されるだろうと思ったのですが，できませんでした．

```
import mechanize

url = "https://kie.nu/22W5"

def kienu(password):
    br = mechanize.Browser()
    br.open(url)
    br.select_form(nr=0)
    br["passwd"] = password
    br.submit()

kienu("full123")
```

なにか良い方法はありませんか？
mechanizeでなくても，目的が達成できればどのような方法でも構いません．

Comment: フォーム内にhiddenがあるのでその値も送信する必要があるかと

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`.submit()`はファイル内容やヘッダを`urllib2.urlopen()`のようにオブジェクトで返します。
中身さえ得られれば良いのならば、関数の最後を

```
    return br.submit().read()
```

などとすれば良いかと思います。
ファイル名が必要であればヘッダの`Content-Disposition`をパースする必要がありますが、それに`cgi.parse_header`が使えるようです。

```
    r = br.submit()
    return (cgi.parse_header(r.info().getheader("content-disposition"))[1]["filename"], r.read())
```

ファイルサイズが小さければこんな所でしょうか。
https://stackoverflow.com/a/27840405
しかし、大きい場合は一気に読まず、ファイルに書き出した方が良いかもしれません。
＃`read()`はファイルなどと同じく読み込みサイズを指定できます
なお蛇足ながら、得られたファイル名にはそのまま使わない方がよい文字種などが含まれる可能性がありますので、場合によっては何らかの変換など行った方が良いかもしれません。

Answer (score 2):

よく引っかかるのは次の2パターンではないでしょうか。

### javascriptが有効でないと利用できない

ブラウザのjavascriptを無効にして確認することが出来ます。

mechanizeはjavascriptが解釈できないはずなので、javascriptが解釈できるツールを使うか、自力でjavascriptの動作をエミュレーションする必要があります。

埋め込みのjavascriptソースで確認できる簡単な処理であれば自力で処理した方が早いかもしれません。ただし、相手側でそこを変更されるとそれに追随しなければなりません。

### 送信する内容が不足または相違している

コメントでも指摘がありますが、ブラウザで表示される入力欄だけでなく、hidden要素やCSSで非表示にされている要素の内容も送信しなければならない場合があります。

Referer:、User-Agent:、Cookieなどがチェックされていることもあります。

ブラウザで正しく操作した場合に送信されている内容を確認し、それに極力合わせるのがよいでしょう。

Answer (score 2):

> 目的が達成できればどのような方法でも構いません

ということですので、コマンドライン上で処理を行う方法を一つ。具体的には curl コマンドを使います。

まず、HTTP レスポンスヘッダだけをダンプしてみます。

```
$ curl -I https://kie.nu/22W5
        : 
Set-Cookie: csrftoken=fba73bc15b49182e7e9be2afe9d6f002; expires=...
```

実は cookie 内の `csrftoken` の値は HTML ファイル内の `csrfmiddlewaretoken`(hidden data) の値と同じです(同じ値で埋め込んでいます)。なので、以下の様にするとダウンロードができます。

```
$ token="$(curl -s -I https://kie.nu/22W5 | grep -Po '(?<=Set-Cookie: csrftoken=).+?(?=;)')"
$ curl -e https://kie.nu/ -b "csrftoken=$token" -d "passwd=full123&csrfmiddlewaretoken=$token" https://kie.nu/22W5 -o output.dat
```

**追記**

実行環境は以下です。

```
$ uname -rvm
3.19.0-30-generic #33-Ubuntu SMP i686
$ curl --version
curl 7.38.0 (i686-pc-linux-gnu)
$ grep --version
grep (GNU grep) 2.20
```

ダウンロードしたファイル

```
$ ls -l output.dat 
-rw-r--r-- 1 nemo nemo 6073 Oct 3 20:20 output.dat

$ od -tx1 output.dat | head
0000000 1b 00 54 00 75 00 78 00 47 00 75 00 69 00 74 00
0000020 61 00 72 00 20 00 46 00 69 00 6c 00 65 00 20 00
                        :
```

Comment: とりあえず上記のコマンドをそのまま実行してみたのですが，得られるファイルはhtml形式で，また実行すると，403 Forbiddenされています．これは，csrfmiddlewareによってはじかれたということでしょうか．

Comment: お使いの OS は OSX でしょうか？ おそらく grep コマンドの `-P` オプションの意味が異なるのだと思います。こちらは Ubuntu Linux です。

Comment: 実行環境を記していませんでしたね．失礼しました．
WindowsでminGWを使用しています．
Ubuntu on Vagrantで行ったところできました．正規表現の部分をいじれば他の環境でも使えるということですね．

Answer (score 1):

おそらく他の方も書かれている通り、クッキー・隠しフォーム・リファラあたりが必須なのでしょう。
**追記: TugrebIcさんの回答で気付きましたが、mechanizeはここらへんを自動でやってくれるはずでしたね。動かない理由は、TugrebIcさんの回答の通りだと思います。**

下記は Python3 の例ですが、いずれスクレイピングも JavaScript の解釈なしでは厳しくなるかと思っています。PhantomJS などを使う方がよいかもしれません。

```
#!/usr/bin/python3
import urllib.request
import http.cookiejar
import re
import sys

url = "https://kie.nu/22W5"

# クッキーを扱う
cookiejar = http.cookiejar.CookieJar()
opener = urllib.request.build_opener(urllib.request.HTTPCookieProcessor(cookiejar))

# 1回目の読み込み(GET)
req = urllib.request.Request(url)
res = opener.open(req)
html = res.readall().decode('utf-8')

# HTML から POST に必要な値を探す
hidden_name = 'csrfmiddlewaretoken'
hidden_input_regex = re.compile(
        "<input[^>]*name='" + hidden_name + "'[^>]*value='([^']*)'[^>]*>")
hidden_value = hidden_input_regex.search(html).group(1)


# 2回目の読み込み(POST)
req.add_header('Referer', url) # たぶん必要
data = {
        'passwd': 'full123',
        hidden_name: hidden_value,
        }
post_data = urllib.parse.urlencode(data).encode(encoding='utf-8')
res = opener.open(req, post_data)

# 標準出力にバイナリのまま出力
sys.stdout.buffer.write(res.readall())
```